# Android delete send sms

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I send sms from my app. I would like to delete send sms from "outbox", because the sms contain PIN code to access devide. The sms is send, but the deleting doesn't work.
The sms exixst, because I'm able to read it in "Cursor c_sms"

```
private void sms_sender(String sms_no, String sms_text) {
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(sms_no, null, sms_text, null, null);
    Toast
            .makeText(MainScreen.this, R.string.text_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    Cursor c_sms = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null, null);
    try{
        while(c_sms.moveToNext()) {
            long id = c_sms.getLong(0);
            String pid = c_sms.getString(0);
            String address = c_sms.getString(2);
            if (address.equals(address)){
                int count = getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id),null,null);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast
                .makeText(MainScreen.this, R.string.text_error + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it crash? Do you catch an exception? Does the code run without crashes, but the sms is still in your outbox? Do you have permission to delete sms messages? Details please...

Comment: Note that you cannot do this on Android 4.4+, unless your app is the user's default SMS client. If that will not be the case, I suggest that you come up with some other way of distributing PIN codes instead of SMS.

Comment: It not crashed, permision I have SMS_READ, SMS_WRITE. Yes, I send the sms, but after deletion the sms is still in the outbox. I compile it for Android 4.4... There are no way how to distribute sms, because the enviroment is sms gateway which manage power switch

Answer (score -1):

getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), "address = ? and body = ?", new String[] {etsendernumber.getText().toString(),etmessagebody.getText().toString()});

use this code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please visit: [How to answer a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). When providing an answer explain further and ident your code properly so it's easier to read.